# .htaccess pretty URL's excluding index.php and adding trailing / to the end

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, friendly-url, trailing-slash, pretty-urls

Ok, I've fought with it for hours. I have 3 different .htaccess scripts which do what I need, but I'm unable to mix them together.

1. Make a pretty url from (example.com/gallery.php -> example.com/gallery)

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ $1.php
   ```
2. The script from #1 though forwards example.com/index.php to example.com/index, so this code removes index.php so example.com/index.php -> example.com

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   # Turn mod_rewrite on
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /

   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s(.*)/index\.php [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L]
   ```
3. The script should add a trailing slash so example.com/gallery -> example.com/gallery/

   ```
   # invoke rewrite engine
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /~new/

   # add trailing slash if missing
   rewriteRule ^(([a-z0-9\-]+/)*[a-z0-9\-]+)$ $1/ [NC,R=301,L]
   ```

Can someone help me to combine those 3 scripts into one universal pretty URL scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add these directives to .htaccess in the root directory of your website

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# add trailing slash

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(/$|\.) 
RewriteRule (.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L] 

# rewrite gallery/ to gallery.php

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php [L]

# redirect example.com/index.php to example.com/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} index\.php$
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works alright, but it adds another problem. It won't load images and styles anymore, it goes to the page, but nothing is loaded, it shows just "empty pic thumbnails" and text from html, I think it's cause the page now thinks the images are in example.com/gallery/images/ while they really are in example.com/images/, any cure for that?

Comment: you should use an absolute path for images and styles

Comment: you mean like "example.com/images/image.jpg" instead of "images/image.jpg", I update the site locally, so it would cause little problems... any way around that?

Comment: Anyways I think I got it working with base url, but it still doesn't load styles in IE, I'll figure it out eventually. Anyways tnx again Amine, I've also added you to my Honorary List on the website I'm building: http://ljis17.com/honorary_list/